# Permissions for non-licensed Office365 users

Tags: permissions, office365

can someone tell me what are the permissions for non-licensed office365 users, specially in an Education tennant?
I've tested it and although no apps appear in the office365 menu(like word, email, etc), the user still has access to sharepoint sites. It shouldn't, right?

Thanks,
Nuno

Comment: Is this about programming?

Comment: no sorry, my mistake.